# How to convert the result of Monte-Carlo Flooding algorithm to set of polygons?

Tags: visualization, polygon, geometry, montecarlo, flooding

I am trying to solve this [problem](http://esgi132.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/Problems/area_partitioning_problem_esgi_132.pdf) by using of [Monte-Carlo Flooding](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TodorBalabanov/ESGI-132-Geometric-Visualization-of-a-Polygon-Area-Partitioning/master/src/Main.java) algorithm. As result I receive set of semicircles (the picture below), but the requested solution is for trapezoid like polygons. Please, can you suggest me an algorithm by which I will be able to transform this semicircles in polygons? [image: Monte-Carlo Flooding Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you extract your pieces as contours, using Suzuki-Abe algorithm (Suzuki, S. and Abe, K., Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following. CVGIP 30 1, pp 32-46 (1985)). You'll get all contours out of your image as they are produced.

Then, you approximate contours into polygons using [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

THere is well-known library which does it all - OpenCV, see link for details https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.2/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am writing a [paper](https://github.com/TodorBalabanov/ESGI-132-Project-2-Report) about this problem. I will reference sources you have provided.